# Running Prepared Statements via Command Line

Tags: mysql, scripting, mariadb, command-line-interface

I am running Pimcore on PHP + MariaDB.. And I need to empty the Pimcore Data Objects via the command line as apart of our rebuild process.

So far I have the following SQL; (outlined below) =>

However when I run it using `mysql < MyScript.sql` I get the following error:
`ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 12: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'NULL' at line 1`.

To make things more confusing, the script runs perfectly fine in an interactive shell. With the PREPARE statements validating the SELECT's and running perfectly.

Does anybody have any idea what is happening? there is no NULL in the script and none of the output generated from the SELECT has any NULLs in it.

Would love to hear your thoughts / ideas!

Cheers!

```
-- Global Overrides
SET GROUP_CONCAT_MAX_LEN=10000;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;
-- DROP VIEWS
SET @VWS = (SELECT CONCAT('DROP VIEW IF EXISTS ', GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(TABLE_SCHEMA, '.', TABLE_NAME) SEPARATOR ', '), ';') AS VWS
FROM information_schema.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'pimcore' AND
TABLE_NAME RLIKE 'object_[0-9]'
ORDER BY TABLE_NAME);
PREPARE REM_VWS FROM @VWS;
EXECUTE REM_VWS;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE REM_VWS;
-- DROP TABLES
SET @TBLS = (SELECT CONCAT('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ', GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(TABLE_SCHEMA, '.', TABLE_NAME) SEPARATOR ', '), ';') AS TBLS
FROM information_schema.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'pimcore' AND
TABLE_NAME RLIKE 'object_store_[0-9]|object_relations_[0-9]|object_query_[0-9]'
ORDER BY TABLE_NAME);
PREPARE REM_TBLS FROM @TBLS;
EXECUTE REM_TBLS;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE REM_TBLS;
-- Global Fixes
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;
```

As requested, here is the output for the TABLES (second statement)

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS pimcore.object_store_129, pimcore.object_relations_118, pimcore.object_store_137, pimcore.object_store_148, pimcore.object_store_141, pimcore.object_query_135, pimcore.object_relations_147, pimcore.object_relations_114, pimcore.object_relations_120, pimcore.object_query_131, pimcore.object_relations_138, pimcore.object_relations_123, pimcore.object_store_111, pimcore.object_store_142, pimcore.object_relations_130, pimcore.object_store_122, pimcore.object_relations_112, pimcore.object_query_103, pimcore.object_query_123, pimcore.object_query_145, pimcore.object_relations_139, pimcore.object_relations_116, pimcore.object_relations_131, pimcore.object_store_134, pimcore.object_query_137, pimcore.object_query_128, pimcore.object_store_125, pimcore.object_store_136, pimcore.object_relations_146, pimcore.object_store_126, pimcore.object_relations_125, pimcore.object_relations_144, pimcore.object_store_124, pimcore.object_query_125, pimcore.object_query_142, pimcore.object_relations_111, pimcore.object_query_133, pimcore.object_query_139, pimcore.object_store_128, pimcore.object_relations_119, pimcore.object_store_147, pimcore.object_relations_134, pimcore.object_query_113, pimcore.object_relations_124, pimcore.object_store_116, pimcore.object_query_141, pimcore.object_relations_107, pimcore.object_relations_145, pimcore.object_query_134, pimcore.object_query_129, pimcore.object_relations_121, pimcore.object_relations_135, pimcore.object_query_130, pimcore.object_store_118, pimcore.object_store_121, pimcore.object_query_117, pimcore.object_query_122, pimcore.object_query_124, pimcore.object_store_123, pimcore.object_store_112, pimcore.object_relations_133, pimcore.object_query_112, pimcore.object_query_111, pimcore.object_relations_132, pimcore.object_query_146, pimcore.object_query_118, pimcore.object_relations_117, pimcore.object_store_127, pimcore.object_store_139, pimcore.object_store_146, pimcore.object_query_148, pimcore.object_relations_148, pimcore.object_store_103, pimcore.object_store_130, pimcore.object_store_117, pimcore.object_store_143, pimcore.object_query_115, pimcore.object_relations_127, pimcore.object_store_138, pimcore.object_store_114, pimcore.object_relations_141, pimcore.object_query_127, pimcore.object_query_114, pimcore.object_relations_129, pimcore.object_query_143, pimcore.object_store_115, pimcore.object_store_132, pimcore.object_query_144, pimcore.object_store_144, pimcore.object_relations_136, pimcore.object_query_147, pimcore.object_query_119, pimcore.object_store_145, pimcore.object_relations_142, pimcore.object_store_135, pimcore.object_relations_115, pimcore.object_query_136, pimcore.object_store_133, pimcore.object_store_119, pimcore.object_store_113, pimcore.object_query_116, pimcore.object_relations_126, pimcore.object_query_107, pimcore.object_query_121, pimcore.object_query_132, pimcore.object_relations_122, pimcore.object_store_107, pimcore.object_relations_128, pimcore.object_relations_103, pimcore.object_query_120, pimcore.object_store_131, pimcore.object_relations_143, pimcore.object_relations_137, pimcore.object_query_138, pimcore.object_query_126, pimcore.object_store_120, pimcore.object_relations_113;
```

Comment: Show us the generated DROP commands.

Comment: Hi @RickJames Thanks for replying! I have added the output for the second statement. Cheers!

Comment: I suggest that you remove the _bash_ tag, because your question is only related to SQL, not to bash. Since the error message refers to line 12, it would be polite if you would point out which line this is.

Comment: I'd expect this to throw NULL if no matching table is found in I_S.tables, so that GROUP_CONCAT() returns NULL ...?